# Colors are not the same in fullscreen mode compared in dos

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am trying to use the fullscreen mode in assembly. I set the color into light blue in dos but whenever I try to incorporate it with my fullscreen mode the color changes. It changes to something like green.

Is there a way for it to be compatible with each other. I am using Tasm; textpad; windows. Thanks.

Here is my macro

```
drawSquare MACRO color,cy,cx,dy,dx
    mov ah,06
    mov al, 0
    mov bh,color
    mov ch,cy
    mov cl,cx
    mov dh,dy
    mov dl,dx
    int 10h
endm
-------------------------------------------------
include macros.txt
.model small
.stack
.data  
    saveMode db ?

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    call SetVideoMode

    drawSquare 90h, 0h, 49h, 18h, 4fh

    call RestoreVideoMode

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
SetVideoMode proc
    mov ah, 0fh
    int 10h
    mov saveMode, al


    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 13h
    int 10h

    push 0A000h
    pop es
    ret
SetVideoMode endp
RestoreVideoMode proc
    mov ah, 10h
    int 16h

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, saveMode
    int 10h
    ret
RestoreVideoMode endp
end main
```

Comment: For DOS only fullscreen video modes exist and DOS does not know about problems with the windows modes of a host system.

Comment: Think about commenting your asm code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set up the 256-colors video mode 13h. Later you paint a box with color 90h.
This doesn't match the color of you DOS screen (text mode) because only the first 16 color numbers match!

If your DOS screen uses BLUE=1 then select color 1 as the first parameter for your macro call.
If your DOS screen uses GREEN=2 then select color 2 as the first parameter for your macro call.

Comment: @random if this solved your problem then I recommend you consider [accepting it as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) .

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i'm a little new here. :D